# Now that Inbox watch app is gone, how do I get Gmail notifications on Apple Watch?

Tags: gmail, apple-watch

So I'm trying to figure out how to get notifications on my Watch. I was using Google's Inbox app but apparently that no longer works.

I don't use Apple Mail, I use G-Mail.

So what are my options?

Comment: If Google discontinued their Apple Watch app then your options are very limited.  Can you use a different mail app or use Apple's default mail app?

Answer (score 1):

According to this, I can get gmail notifications in iOS 11.

Oops, here is the link: https://9to5mac.com/2017/06/06/ios-11-appears-to-restore-gmail-push-in-apple-mail/

Comment: According to what?

Comment: The linked story has nothing to do with Apple Watch. It's also specifically talking about the Apple Mail app getting push notifications restored, NOT the Gmail or Inbox apps. Those were getting push notifications the whole time. It's also an old story about iOS 11 beta. Original question seemed to be "If there is no Inbox watch app, how can I get notifications?" My answer addressed that and I get downvoted :/

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is: install Microsoft Outlook on your iPhone. This will add Outlook on your iWatch and also an application for the dials. Notifications working fine, full mails with options to answer, delete and so on ...
I've deleted Gmail-App and the native Mail App on my iPhone.